# How to pass an Event object in Unity?

Tags: c#, object, events, unity-game-engine

Let's say I have 3 GUI buttons in my scene. To each of these buttons I add a Pointer Enter and Pointer Exit event trigger in the inspector. The event is handled in a script which is added to an empty game object. The functions are totally trivial right now:

```
public void OnPointerEnter() {
    print("in");
}

public void OnPointerLeave() {
    print("out");
}
```

It works fine but I wonder how I could identify which button was hovered without passing some string / number in the inspector panel. Is there some event object sent in? I cannot seem to find anything. Or is it not possible at all?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not add it to your buttons and use the "this" keyword? In which you would receive something like {button(exit)} and then handle?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function `public void OnPointerEnter(Button b){}` and statically define the button from the inspector, though this wont change at run time and will always pass the same value for the instance of that component.

The new Event systems has 2 modes, dynamic and static,

The static mode can take in one arg at most, ie the "SetActive" function on game object can be set to be called with the same value of true/false every time, which is defined in the inspector (this works for bool, string, and anything inheriting from "UnityEngine.Object")

The dynamic mode is the one that has types defined in the event, IE Toggle can pass in a dynamic bool on each "Click" event that is defined by the class that calls "x.Invoke(m_IsToggled)", The dynamic version can however be used as a static version, by using the "Static" functions that you see in the drop down.

However in your case the EventTrigger class uses a UnityEvent without any dynamic values to pass through, so you can only use the static version and call a function that takes in a single argument that is either, bool, string, or anything that inherits from "UnityEngine.Object"